# How to change the application launcher name with different build flavors and different locale of user in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, android-studio

I want to change the application launcher name by build flavors and the locale of user.
Assume, i build four application with different build flavors and locale and the match name :

```
  + First : Build flavor is free and locale is en => App Free English
  + Second: Build flavor is premium and locale is vn => App Premium Vietnam
  + Third: Build flavor is beta and locale is ko => App Beta Korean
  + Four: Build flavor is premium and locale is ko => App Premium Korean
```

So, how can i do like this ?

I try resValue "string", "app_name", "App Name", but the name just change by build flavor.

Answer (score 0):

Provide app name in your *productFlavors or buildTypes* section of **build.gradle(app-level)** like below

```
// productFlavors or buildTypes section 
{
   ....
   applicationIdSuffix '.testapp'
   resValue "string", "app_name", "App Name"
   ....
}
```

Also make sure you reference the value **app_name** to **android:label** in   your **AndroidManifest.xml** file as below:

```
 <application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    ...
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
...
...
</application>
```

**EDIT:**

You can also reference you app name like below if you have multiple flavor setup.

```
    productFlavors {
    appFree {
        applicationId "com.example.testapp.free"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        buildConfigField "String", "type", "\"Free\""

        // app_name should reference to android:label property in AndroidManifest file
        resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/app_name_free"
        return true
    }
    appPremium {
        applicationId "com.example.testapp.premium"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        buildConfigField "String", "type", "\"Paid\""
        resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/app_name_premium"
        return true
    }
}
```

Note: you will need to setup separate string.xml file for each locale like below:

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name_free">TestApp free</string>
<string name="app_name_premium">TestApp premium</string>
</resources>
```

**vn\strings.xml**

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name_free">TestApp miễn phí</string>
<string name="app_name_premium">TestApp trả phí</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Yes, tried this. But it is not my expect, i want when at different locale it will different name too.

Comment: @KhangPham I have edited my answer. Please check it out.